# Method to Log errors on Try-Catch Automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, overriding, try-catch

I have a class that send my exception to the database, and save the Error. but I have to put it inside each `try {} catch{..my method here..}`, and that because I have a Error log, Its a big application, and I would like to override the catch, that every time the application enter to a catch, it execute my method and send the exception and the stack-trace to the database.

Sorry is my English is not good.

PD. I develop using MVC.NET 4 Razor

Comment: If you're developing a web app, use NuGet to install ELMAH, point it at your database and call it a day.

Comment: After the PD (PS), ELMAH may be what you want. But note that it only does the error logging, not the proper error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking into using ELMAH ([available here](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC)), which describes how to integrate this with an MVC project.

Alternatively you could also use log4net, but this would have to be called from within your catch statement.

Comment: Hey, I just want fire my event earch time a catch is handled

Comment: You could use a method similar to the answer by Henk Holterman, and then within that method you either log the error through log4net or through ELMAH.

Comment: I have my own method, and I execute the same method throw all my try catch, But sometimes I forget to put the metod inside a catch, And I just want to develop a override or a event that handle my method each time the catch is handled.

Comment: hey, I intall ELMAH, and it doent log me the try {} catch {...} exception, I would like it to log all the exceptions, I comment that I have my proyect divided in diferents Class proyect In the mvc I just have the views and the controller and in an other class proyect I have, my repositoy, How can I configure ELMAH to audit all my errors.

Comment: Did you follow the setup guide on the link I posted in the answer?